# How to lock a hopper once it has picked up an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have 6 shulker boxes in a dispenser, they travel by hopper down a line of dispensers they can end up in, I want to have 1 end up in each of the 6 dispensers, so if I run a hopper line across all the dispensers, is there a way to lock a hopper from taking a shulker box if it already has?

EDIT:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: Second Solution]
If you must have your items feeding into the side of the dispenser, try this method instead! Start with the redstone block on **top**, not on the bottom like where it is in the picture. (Oops, bad picture!)

That aside, with the redstone block on top, the hopper is now ready to receive items. When an item is detected by the comparator, it pushes the redstone block down, which turns the redstone torch on and locks the hopper. To reset it and enable the hopper to again accept one more item, just provide a short pulse to the bottom piston to push the redstone block back up.

This solution is also one wide and tileable, like my [previous one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/371989/250180). Like my previous one, you will also have to limit the rate the items flow in (maybe by slowing down the dropper clock in the top left of your screenshot?).

Comment: Please always test your MCJava answers in MCJava. Redstone especially is known to behave very differently between the two games.

Comment: @FabianRöling I know that. But this example behaves the same in MCJE, with *no difference* in behaviour. Knowing that there will be no difference in behaviour is enough for me to accept it as a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although you might have to space the Hoppers a bit more for this to work.
If you don't plan on shooting the Shulker Box out of the Dispenser right as it receives it, place a Redstone Comparator that will receive signal from the Dispenser, transmit it to a Redstone Repeater, then **deliver a Redstone signal to the Hopper, which will lock it.**
*If you need more clarifications, I'll add a scheme here.*

Comment: Thank you could you please clarify with a scheme?

Comment: @SneakySteve Ok, but it might take a little while.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question, but it probably solves your problem:

Run a chest minecart over the hopper line. At maximum speed and quite a bit below that as well, this puts exactly one item into each hopper.